# Using IOptions with Unity

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a Class Library that is referenced from a ASP.Net Core (targeting 4.5) and a 4.5 web app and I want to have shared App Settings. I am using Unity for DI on the 4.5 side, and Core Bootstrapping on the Core side. On the Core side, I register a type of my App Settings like so

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

I then reference AppSettings like so

```
private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;
public SubmissionRepository(PricingContext dbContext, IMapper mapper, IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
{
     _appSettings = appSettings;
}
```

I want to register my services on the 4.5 side, I was able to do this in WebApiConfig.cs with Unity

```
container.RegisterType<AppSettings>(new InjectionFactory(o => BuildAppSettings()));
```

where BuildAppSettings just populates an instance of that type using ConfigurationManager (not sure if this is the right way to do it)

However I get an Exception at Runtime

> Unable to cast object of type '.Core.Integration.Models.AppSettings'
>   to type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Core.Integration.Models.AppSettings]'.

I am guessing I need to somehow put IOptions instance into my container, but not sure how to do this. Is there a preferred/better way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

If I would have Googled for 10 more seconds, I would have found this

```
Options.Create(new AppSettings{
    // config reads
});
```

Comment: here's a working singleton hard-coded example that I used: `Container.RegisterInstance(Options.Create(new MemoryDistributedCacheOptions()));`